Iteratively using Reap/Sow
It's my understanding that using Reap/Sow can be far more efficient than other list building methods. Most of the time I'm building lists it's done iteratively, so how would I use them in this manner? For a quick and easy example consider Brownian motion simulated as follows
r = {{0, 0, 0}}
dt = .0000001
Do[AppendTo[r, 
  r[[i]] + 
   dt*{RandomReal[{-.1, .1}], RandomReal[{-.1, .1}], 
     RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}], {i, 1, 10}]
r

How would this be done using Reap/Sow?

You can use Reap/Sow, but there is no merit in doing so when there is no conditional branching. r = Accumulate[RandomReal[dt*{-.1, .1}, {10000, 3}]] is about 500 times faster than your code with {i, 1, 10000}.

Well this is an EXTREMELY reductive case.  What I do is usually requiring several intermediate steps, and I don't see how more complex cases will work with Accumulate.

I see your point. Then how about putting a code which you really want to do fast? Then, people would present an optimized solution.

Your example with Reap/sow:
last = {0, 0, 0};
dt = .0000001;
Reap[Do[Sow[
    last + dt*{RandomReal[{-.1, .1}], RandomReal[{-.1, .1}], 
       RandomReal[{-.1, .1}]}], {i, 1, 10}]
  ][[2]]


